# Pass variable from directives to controller

Tags: angularjs

How can I pass the value of directive to the controller or pass a variable from directives to controller. Thank you.

This is my code. It has the variable under the $observe function

```
.directive("groupId", function () {
     return {
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('groupId', function(value) {  
        myVal = value;
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: need to add scope definition to the declaration of directive

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <!--* groupIdValue value is passing from controller to directive
     * and my-val is returned back from directive to controller
     * that value is available to controller from ControllerVar variable *-->
    <tr group-id="{{groupIdValue}}" my-val="ControllerVar"></tr>
  </table>
  controller variable: {{ControllerVar}}
</body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.groupIdValue = '123345';
  }).directive("groupId", function() {
    return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        myVal: "=myVal"
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('groupId', function(value) {
          scope.myVal = value;
        });
      }
    };
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Here you  can use `ControllerVar` in your controller as `$scope.ControllerVar`.

Comment: thank you. how can I pass the scope.myVal value to the controller, how would i call it?

Comment: Change `<group-id my-val="ControllerVar"></group-id>` to `<div  group-id my-val="ControllerVar"></div>` and use `restrict:'A'`

Comment: use `$scope.ControllerVar` inside controller, it will have same value of `scope.myVal` inside directive.

Comment: here's the html element <tr group-id="{{ group.Id }}"></tr>

Comment: thank you for the replies. I still cant output the value {{group.id}} to controller from directive.

Comment: is this right? <div group-id my-val="ControllerVar"></div>

Comment: Please see newly added snippet.